# Node js error handling with callbacks in nested functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this kind of error handling is not right, promises should be used instead, but I am wondering if it could work as it is:

```
router.get('/main', function(req, res, next) {
var myCallback = new function(err, data){
    if(err) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: "Error (best handling ever)" });
            return;
        }
            res.send("Success");
            return;
    };
    mainProcess(myCallback);
});


function mainProcess(callback){
    request.post(requestParams, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            callback.return(error, "");
        } else {
            request.post(requestParams, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                    callback.return(error, "");
                } else {
                    // Success  
                    callback.return(null, "Success");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I could test it myself, but I need to know whether callback that was passed as a parameter could be used in nested functions and whether it's the right approach.

Comment: Technically it can be used. I would have used "async" module in such case. The suitable function would be "async.waterfall". I am not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Just use `function () {}` don't use `new function()`

Comment: @SagarGopale thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: @slebetman, ou yes sure, thank you.